# Ошибка "command not found: mysql"

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, mamp

Изучаю `php` и `mysql` по книге. Дошел до раздела с `mysql`. Там описывается, что надо ввести команду `mysql -h имя_хоста -u имя_пользователя -p`, а терминал мне пишет `command not found: mysql`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать дальше или хотя бы в каком направлении искать.

`mysql` уже установил и в момент вызова команды `mysql` сервер запущен.

Или может быть как то через `mamp` можно?

ОС: `macOS High Sierra`.

Comment: значит mysql у вас не в путях автоматического поиска команд. найдите где он лежит и добавьте этот путь в PATH (или где там это в вашей ОС) или запускайте указывая полный путь до исполнимого файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, используете `MAMP` на `macOS`. Банарник `mysql` у `MAMP` лежит вот тут

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
```

Можно добавить в файл `~/.bash_profile` строчку

```
alias mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
```

или запускать напрямую через терминал командой:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u username -p password
```

Comment: Alias? Может лучше просто экспортировать дополнительный путь через PATH?

Comment: пожалуйста `export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql`